# I've just deleted my /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols directory and restarted, how come I can still type?

Tags: x11, xkb

I'm running Linux Mint and I'm trying to edit my symbol files but none of the changes stick - I've tried restarting X and restarting the computer. Eventually I got frustrated and tried deleting the symbols directory (well, moving it to the parent directory), and if that had made a difference I'd revert the change using a TTY. I restarted the computer but I can still type - why is that?

More information: the only directories I have found relating to xkb (I used `locate xkb`), are those in `/usr/share/X11/xkb` and its subdirectories, and so these are the files I've been editing.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I have a similar problem, that I was just about to migrate to this site instead. http://askubuntu.com/questions/330885/why-arent-my-modifications-to-xkb-working

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool made by XFree/X.org in order to alter your symbol / key mapping. It is xmodmap. See [this post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) for a nice explanation about it from ArchLinux community. Default keyboard configuration file on Debian-based Linux (Ubuntu, Linux Mint, etc) is in **/etc/default/keyboard**.

You can also do that with [tools like](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugterminal.html) getkeycodes / setkeycodes or dumpkeys / loadkeys. Take note that those tools works only in a *real* console, not a xterm. You'll need to use CTRL+ALT+FX.

Comment: Supposedly, xkb is now preferred over xmodmap anyway.